# Combination of week and year as filter using sql in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to use two combo boxes as the filter. The first combo box (cbxGroupBy) is by week,month and year. The second combo box (cbxYear) has the actual years (2017,2018,2019).

For example, I want to build chart using filter by week of 2017. The following code uses only first combo box by week, month or year. How do I add codes to combine the second filter of actual years.

```
SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date=DATEPART(" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + ", SaleDate),                                                                                                                                       
                       SUM (Total) AS Amount                            
                       FROM SaleSummary                          
                       GROUP BY DATEPART(" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + ", SaleDate)")


        Chart2.DataSource = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)
        Chart2.Series.Clear() 
        Chart2.Series.Add("Total Revenue")
        Chart2.Series("Total Revenue").XValueMember = "Date"
        Chart2.Series("Total Revenue").YValueMembers = "Amount"
```

Comment: Week of Year is a Calendar thing not a Date thing.   Unless it is part of the table, how do you propose to calculate it?

Comment: @Plutonix I can get the chart based on week, month or year using the above code. My issue is I need to use both week and year (actual year).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Are you asking how to write the SQL query to filter by both week and year? Or the SQL to group by both (which is what your current example is doing)? Or something in the VB code?

Comment: Why not add a Where statement to filter the actual year from cbxYear.

Comment: @JohnnyFitz thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Where to filter the Year

```
SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date=DATEPART(" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + ", SaleDate),                                                                                                                                       
                       SUM (Total) AS Amount                            
                       FROM SaleSummary 
                       WHere Year( SaleDate) = " +  Me.cbxYear.Text  + "                     
                       GROUP BY DATEPART(" + Me.cboxGroupBy.Text + ", SaleDate)")


        Chart2.DataSource = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)
        Chart2.Series.Clear() 
        Chart2.Series.Add("Total Revenue")
        Chart2.Series("Total Revenue").XValueMember = "Date"
        Chart2.Series("Total Revenue").YValueMembers = "Amount"
```